# Unity3D Android App Crashes Immediately On All Phones.

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, device, logcat

Hey everyone and thanks for reading.

I have made an app on Unity3D And I'm ready to test it on my Android phone (Huawei G510). It crashes as soon as I try to open the app on my phone (doesn't even display splash screen).

I have been advised to check out the LogCat file, but realistically I am a complete noob and after trying to decipher the error messages for hours I am at my wit's end.

All apps I have tried to deploy instantly Crash

All devices I have tested, crash the app (Galaxy S3, S2 and my Huawei)

I am running a Macbook Pro, have downloaded the Eclipse SDK and also the Java JDK, as well as installing ALL of the SDK versions available.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stumped :(.

Here is the logcat file (I have posted the errors I can pick out underneath all of the stuff logcat output)

```
 W/lights  (  386): TP Button Light current value is 255 
 W/lights  (  386): button_backlight:property_get,percent =50
 E/Trace   (13928): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 W/dalvikvm(13928): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
 E/dalvikvm(  386): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2248K, 35% free 16308K/25031K, paused 34ms+14ms, total 237ms
 I/Unity   (13928): gles_mode = 0 (integer)
 I/Unity   (13928): splash_mode = 0 (integer)
 I/Unity   (13928): hide_status_bar = True (bool)
 I/Unity   (13928): useObb = False (bool)
 I/Unity   (13928): development_player = True (bool)
 I/Unity   (13928): onResume
 I/Unity   (13928): windowFocusChanged: true
 I/ActivityManager(  386): Displayed com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: +1s110ms
 E/Unity   (13928): Invalid serialized file version. File: "/data/app/com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/mainData". Expected version: 4.3.3f1. Actual version: 4.3.0f4.
 E/Unity   (13928):  
 E/Unity   (13928): (Filename: Runtime/Serialize/SerializedFile.cpp Line: 735)
 E/Unity   (13928): 
 E/Unity   (13928): Failed to read file '/data/app/com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/mainData' because it is corrupted.
 E/Unity   (13928):  
 E/Unity   (13928): (Filename: Runtime/Serialize/SerializedFile.cpp Line: 450)
 E/Unity   (13928): 
 E/Sensors (  386): GsSensor: line +83 ~~~handle===0~~en==1~~!n
 W/InputDispatcher(  386): channel '41d880f8 com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
 E/InputDispatcher(  386): channel '41d880f8 com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
 E/Sensors (  386): GsSensor::setDelay: line +114 ~~~handle===0~~ns==200000000~~
 E/Sensors (  386): GsSensor::setDelay: line +114 ~~~handle===0~~ns==200000000~~
 W/InputDispatcher(  386): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41d880f8 com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)'
 E/Sensors (  386): GsSensor: line +83 ~~~handle===0~~en==0~~!n
 E/Sensors (  386): GsSensor::setDelay: line +114 ~~~handle===0~~ns==200000000~~
 I/fitatc  (  633): no preference set
 W/lights  (  386): TP Button Light current value is 0 
 W/lights  (  386): button_backlight:property_get,percent =50
```

##################### HERE ARE THE BUGS THAT I THINK MIGHT BE THE PROBLEM BUT COULD BE WRONG.

```
 E/Trace   (13928): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)


 W/dalvikvm(13928): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'


 E/Unity   (13928): Invalid serialized file version. File: "/data/app/com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/mainData". Expected version: 4.3.3f1. Actual version: 4.3.0f4.


 E/Unity   (13928): Failed to read file '/data/app/com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/mainData' because it is corrupted.



 W/InputDispatcher(  386): channel '41d880f8 com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9


 E/InputDispatcher(  386): channel '41d880f8 com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!



 W/InputDispatcher(  386): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '41d880f8 com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
E/Unity   (13928): Invalid serialized file version. File: "/data/app/com.BlueBeanie.HungryBarns-1.apk/assets/bin/Data/mainData". Expected version: 4.3.3f1. Actual version: 4.3.0f4.
```

It looks like there's a conflict in version numbers. If you upgraded (or downgraded) Unity in the middle of the project, it's the likely cause. Based on [this forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/96415-Asset-bundle-and-Invalid-serialized-file-version-problem-after-upgrading-unity), it looks like you need to start a new xcode project every time you upgrade Unity. I know Unity projects can be upgraded to a newer version, but they will be broken if they're ever opened with an older version.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try that, and upgrade everything to the newest versions and run it again!

Comment: I want to kiss you on the mouth because you were right <333333

Comment: You are so smarrrrrrrrt

Answer (score 2):

For my case of Android, just simply replace *libunity.so* in my Android project with the new version of *libunity.so* exported by new version of Unity.
There's actually no need to create a new Android project.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are more visitors to this question, I was having the same issue when building with a Huawei tablet from a MacBook Pro, exactly as you describe. We managed to solve it by unchecking "Development Build" in the "Build Setting" dialog.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: I was also using a macbook pro! Possible bug?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your unity exported folder. In libs folder, you will find `armeabi-v7a`, `x86` folders and `unity-classes.jar` file according to your player settings.

Move and replace `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` folders into your `<yourandroidproject>/app/src/main/jniLibs/` folder.

Move and replace `unity-classes.jar` file into your `<yourandroidproject>/app/libs/` folder.

If you cannot find the paths that I mention, search for their names in your android project and replace them with the new ones accordingly.